# Create columns in dataframe from list (Number of columns change)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm working with a pandas dataframe and I have a problem.

My input is a list and I don't know how many elements there are in the list, it could be anything from 1 to 5 or 6. I need to add new columns to the dataframe, one for each element in the list.

Currently, I add comments to lines, but it doesn't work automatically. My code:

```
list = ['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi'] (3 elements, so i comment 2 lines)

df.loc[:, list[0]] = np.where(df['food'] == list[0], 1.0, 0.0)
df.loc[:, list[1]] = np.where(df['food'] == list[1], 1.0, 0.0)
df.loc[:, list[2]] = np.where(df['food'] == list[2], 1.0, 0.0)
#df.loc[:, list[3]] = np.where(df['food'] == list[3], 1.0, 0.0)
#df.loc[:, list[4]] = np.where(df['food'] == list[4], 1.0, 0.0)
```

I would loke to have something that reads the number of elements in the list, and then creates the correct number of columns automatically, without # adding comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in pandas is best avoid loops, so use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with filtered rows by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
L = ['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi']
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.loc[df['food'].isin(L), 'food'])
```

Last add `0` rows and add to original use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(df1.reindex(df1.index, fill_value=0.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by simply using a for-loop:

```
l= ['banana', 'apple', 'kiwi']

for fruit in l:
    df.loc[:, fruit] = np.where(df['food'] == fruit, 1.0, 0.0)
```